# Why change of custom.css in "clean" of Moodle theme is not working?

Tags: php, layout, themes, moodle

I'm working with `Moodle Framework`, so I need change layout of `clean` theme, in the [document](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Clean_theme) is written:

```
/style/custom.css 
This is where all the settings CSS is generated.
```

But why my change in the `custom.css` is not affect in my layout?

Comment: is there any custom.min.css file also? are you sure this file is not being overwritten too?

Comment: in style folder has only custom.css file, and is not being overwritten too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might be caching. On your development machine add this to your `config.php`

```
$CFG->themedesignermode = true;
```

Only do this when designing though, Moodle will be very slow otherwise. Remove it or set it to false when you are finished designing.

I wouldn't recommend putting it on a production server.

https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Theme_Designer_Mode

Answer (score 1):

sometime you need to clear the cache of theme to apply your customization at style by go to site administration > appearance > theme selector then click clear cache button